# I had this error in Eclipse and in Netbeans it works fine

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000010000000000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at cmpe363_project.Register.binaryToDecimalHelper(Register.java:163)
    at cmpe363_project.Emulator.startProgram(Emulator.java:103)
    at cmpe363_project.CMPE363_project.main(CMPE363_project.java:27)
```

Comment: If you have a piece of code that is not working, please show that code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is larger than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) which means it simply does not fit into an `int`.

Use [`Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to read a value that is too big to fit in an integer.

(Max Integer  = 2,147,483,647)  <  (value being read = 10,000,000,000)

Instead of reading the value into an Integer, read the value into a Long